# curl: fetch matched information by a column?

Tags: csv, curl

I am trying to fetch the information by string match.
The links look like below: 
http://www.informatics.jax.org/marker/MGI:95640

http://www.informatics.jax.org/marker/MGI:87904

......

The numbers "95640", "87904"... are in a column in my local csv file. 
My target string is flanked by < blockquote > and < /blockquote >:

< blockquote >Mutant heterozygotes show reduced enzyme levels. The currently known mutant allels are homozygous lethal.< /blockquote >

How can I fetch the information between the two marks with curl and add it to the corresponding rows in the original csv file?